# JPA named Query getResultList() in generic way

Tags: java, generics, jpa

I want result list from JPA Named query in generic way like `List<ProjectLevel<?>>`. I need this as I wanted to stream it later.

`ProjectLevel` is a generic class.

```
public abstract class ProjectLevel<T extends ProjectLevel>{
....
}
```

adding subClass of ProjectLevel as suggested.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"businessAccountId", "id"})})
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Project.findByProjectIdOrUUID",
                query = "SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE (p.id = :id OR p.uuid = :id) and p.businessAccountId = :businessAccountId")
})
public class Project extends ProjectLevel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2167149510293504460L;

    @Nonnull
    private String customerUUID;

    @Nonnull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Currency currency;

    @Nonnull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ProjectType projectType;

    @Nonnull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ContractType contractType;

    @Nonnull
    private String cityLocation;

    private boolean locationPermission;

    private boolean insuranceRequired;
}
```

I tried this but it gives me typecasting error like

> incompatible types: `List<ProjectLevel>` cannot be converted to
>   `List<ProjectLevel<?>>`

from getResultList() line

```
    public List<ProjectLevel<?>> findUUIDByNameorNumber(@Nonnull final String nameOrId,
                                                        @Nonnull final String businessAccountId) {
        checkNotNull(nameOrId, "The nameOrId must not be null");

        return (List<ProjectLevel<?>>)getEntityManager()
                .createNamedQuery("ProjectLevel.findUUIDByNameOrId", ProjectLevel.class)
                .setParameter("name", matchesFromBeginning(nameOrId))
                .setParameter("businessAccountId", businessAccountId)
                .getResultList();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Kindly add the full error information (stacktrace, compiler error?)

Comment: @GhostCat updated my question

Comment: Would `List<ProjectLevel<T>>` be fine as return type or do you absolutely want `List<ProjectLevel<?>>` ?

Comment: `List<ProjectLevel<?>>` would be better. Let me add my ProjectLevel entity

Comment: Your ProjectLevel use a raw type. References to generic type ProjectLevel<T> should be parameterized. Add a extedended class from ProjectLevel.

Comment: @jklee you mean to post sub class of `ProjectLevel`?

Comment: yes, with annotations.

Comment: @jklee I don't know how it would help you but still updated my question.

Comment: Your IDE doesn't show a warning? I think you use generics wrong. Project is extended by a raw type. What is T at class Project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know it's a valid solution or not but,
I resolve this by removing resultClass argument from createNamedQuery.

> resultClass - the type of the query result

Also, it will throw `IllegalArgumentException` if mismatch the type. 
From doc:

> IllegalArgumentException - if a query has not been defined with the
>   given name or if the query string is found to be invalid or if the
>   query result is found to not be assignable to the specified type

So, I changed my method to this. And it works fine for now.

```
@Nonnull
public List<ProjectLevel<?>> findUUIDByNameorNumber(@Nonnull final String nameOrId,
                                                    @Nonnull final String businessAccountId) {
    checkNotNull(nameOrId, "The nameOrId must not be null");

    return getEntityManager()
            .createNamedQuery("ProjectLevel.findUUIDByNameOrId")
            .setParameter("name", matchesFromBeginning(nameOrId))
            .setParameter("businessAccountId", businessAccountId)
            .getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic class might look like this.

```
@Entity(name="ProjectLevel")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@NamedQuery(name="ProjectLevel.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM ProjectLevel p") 
public class ProjectLevel<T> implements Serializable {
   ...
}



@Entity
public class ProjectLevelString extends ProjectLevel<String>{

    String projectLevel;

}



@Entity
public class ProjectLevelInteger extends ProjectLevel<Integer>{

    Integer projectLevel;

}
```

You can select all ProjectLevel with

```
List<ProjectLevel<?>> resultList = entityManager.createNamedQuery("ProjectLevel.findAll").getResultList();
```

Comment: I need to apply namedQuery here.

Comment: Yes. but i do not needed to change any generic class. Only i remove resultClassType and it worked. Thank you for your efforts.